# FCPX 10.1.3 - How Do I Copy Project?

Tags: editing, final-cut-pro-x, final-cut-pro, workflow, apple

Super-basic question, I know, and yes I'm a total noob.

I have a simple project in my timeline that I'd like to save (so I can go back to it in the future and make edits) but then move forward with what I've got so far as the basis for a new project, and swap out a few clips.

I've read everything I can find online in the vein of "how to copy/duplicate projects/events", but have struck out (which makes me think maybe I don't understand the nomenclature at work here).

Anyway,two other possibly salient facts:

1. There are no projects in my browser, only clips
2. Menu items "Edit/Duplicate/Duplicate Project as Snapshot" are grayed out

Any thoughts? Tia!

Answer (score 1):

To freeze your current state of work you need to load a Library and right click on a Project. Important is you need to choose Duplicate as Snapshot. Only then you make a protected copy of your current work. 
Here is why: When you have compounded clips in your project, these clips living outside of your project, available to all Projects in the Library. When you Duplicate your Project only, any change you make inside a Compound Clip is rippling to any Project what is a duplicate to this Project you working on and has this completed Clip in your timeline. 
Here is a link to a video that shows the effect. Watch maybe a couple of times as the guy is kind of fuzzy on his explanation.
[Duplicate vs Duplicate as Snapshot](https://youtu.be/IUYgokwh_Oc)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the option for duplicating a project is grayed out in your case. 
You already wrote the solution. You select a project within an event, an than you can right click on it and select to duplicate it or to duplicate it as a snapshot.

Here is a screenshot (german)
[image]

Just select the project you want to duplicate and than right click on it or use the menu.